# How to trigger 'contenteditable' element into edit state using js?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to implement element in-placing edit using 'contenteditable' attribute. Is it possible to go into the edit state with mouse event simulation instead of user click?

```
function triggerEvent(element, eventType) {
    let rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  console.log(rect);

    let event = new MouseEvent(eventType, {
    clientX: rect.left + 20,
    clientY: rect.top + 10,
    view: window,
    buttons: 1,
    bubbles: true,
  });
  element.dispatchEvent(event);
}

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    let editArea = document.getElementById('edit-area');
  editArea.setAttribute('contenteditable', true);

  triggerEvent(editArea, 'mousedown');
});
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/lfree/vkeq9fza/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to `focus` the div:

```js
let div = document.querySelector('div');

div.focus();
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">Div Content</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, all you're trying to do is set focus to the element. Because you've already enabled `contenteditable`, the following should be adequate:

```
editArea.setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
editArea.focus(); // Focus on the input which will activate editing
```