# Show underlining immediately when html element has contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true"

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, spell-checking

I would like to highlight misspelling in a span on page load, e.g.,

```
<span contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true">gibberishnonesense</span>
```

Currently, the `gibberishnonesense` does not underline unless I click into the span. I would like the underlining to happen on page load. It seem that the underlining only happens once you actively start to edit.

Is there a setting I need to switch to this is underlined without editting? Is there an event I can send to the span that will activate it - and not change the `activeElement` or focus (avoid [`el.focus();`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41776760/689554)?

I am aware of styling with `text-decoration-style: wavy;` but that underline style is different and I would like to leverage the user agent's spellchecker.

===
Things I have tried:

Changing the elements content via JS

```
el.innerText += ''
```

Sending a "change" event via JS

```
var manualChange = new Event('change');
el.dispatchEvent(manualChange);
```

===

Some research indicates this is a Chrome specific behavior; however, I am targeting Chrome and therefore need it to work there.

I see from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21125380/689554) that there is a [`forceSpellchek` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/forceSpellCheck) which is not yet implemented in Chrome

Comment: Perhaps on page load, using JS, simulate a click on the element to invoke the browsers' spellcheck. Worst-case scenario, if this is crucial for your app, you could use a JS spellcheck library (there are some), and that will give you full control over the experience.

Answer (score 0):

I have never found a satisfactory solution to this - as you say, spell-check doesn't kick in until you click in the contenteditable document.

The only answer I came up with is to insert a banner (eg: div) on load at the start of the document, saying 'Click to activate spell-check' - then on click, delete the div.

The very act of clicking on the div activates spell-check, but it's a bit clumsy and as all my users create articles from new I eventually dropped it.

I also believe spell-check kicks in on insert, so that might be a route worth investigating - it's not something I've tried.